# How to set reactive object in Vuejs 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a reactive object in the global space:

```
let cart = Vue.reactive({
    order: {
       itemsCount: 0
    },
    items: []
});
```

It works great. When we change this cart in any way (for example `cart.order.itemsCount += 1;`) other UI parts get updated automatically.

But if we set it to a new object (let's say we have received a new `order` object from server) then it breaks and won't work anymore:

```
cart = serverCart
```

We even tried `cart = Vue.reactive(serverCart)` and it still does not cause other UI parts to re-render.

It's possible that we set every property manaully:

```
cart.order.itemsCount = serverCart.order.ItemsCount;
cart.items[0].productTitle = serverCart.order[0].productTitle;
...
```

But this is idiotic of course.

How can we re-set a reactive object entirely in Vue.js 3?

**Update**:

You can see this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-flower-orz832?file=/index.html) in action.

Comment: What if you do cart = {...serverCart} ?

Comment: @digitalniweb, did not work

Answer (score 5):

For setting new values reactive objects in vue3, you need to use `Object.assign` function and you should not reassign it

Here is an example:

```
<template>
  {{ reactiveTest }}
  <button @click="change">Change</button>
</template>

<script>
import { reactive } from "vue";
export default {
  setup() {
    let reactiveTest = reactive({
      a: 1,
      b: 2,
    });
    function change() {
      const serverReactive = {
        a: 3,
        b: 4,
      };
      // reactiveTest = serverReactive;  Do not do this
      Object.assign(reactiveTest, serverReactive)
    }
    return {
      reactiveTest,
      change,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Does not work. Please see my codesandbox.

Comment: Change line 59 to this:
```//cart = { ...newCart };
Object.assign(cart, newCart);```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-flower-orz832?file=/index.html)

Comment: Yeah, I saw, it works in the code sandbox. But strangely it still does not work in my code and there is no error. However, your solution apparently works. Thank you.

Comment: Object.assign wont work, you can see that in vue console, it's stays apart from other data, which is pushed/popped from that array

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to copy by reference, try to copy by value with spread operator `...` :

```js
const { reactive } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  el: "#demo",
  setup() {
    let cart = reactive({
      order: {
         itemsCount: 0
      },
      items: []
    });
    
    const someCart = {order: {itemsCount: 3}, items: [{id: 1, name: "aaa"}, {id: 2, name: "bbb"}, {id: 3, name: "444"}]}
    
    cart = reactive({...someCart})
    
    return {cart }
  }
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
    <p> {{ cart }}</p>
    <label>change items count</label>
    <input type="number" v-model="cart.order.itemsCount" />
</div>
```

Comment: It does not work. See this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-flower-orz832?file=/index.html)

Comment: @Ali EXE hey mate, what doesn't work ? when you click on `load entire cart` you get the right count

Comment: Yeah, it works now, because I have used the other answer. I used `Object.assign` not `destructuring assignemnt`.